# Magento 2.2.6 - grouped product's associated product assign issue while having custom options in admin

Tags: custom-options, magento2.2.6, grouped-products, product-grid, associated-products

[image]I have a problem in assigning the associated products of it's group product in admin area of magento 2.2.6. while having the custom options.

when i add the simple products but not display in the grid , please let me know if any perfect solution you have.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Can you check you have added custom options as required options? that may cause the issue.

Comment: yes thanks but that i knew it already, sorry for not mentioned in my questions. so using that required that cause the issue. if we removed that checkbox tick than that will work like a charm so .. is this magento's default issue , ? how should i  solve it? @ParthThummar

Comment: actually i had a migration from m1-> m2 so in that some of the products are grouped , among those products i am not able to see all the associated products. some of the products are working fine. please let me know the solution Thanks  @ParthThummar

Comment: Magento Out of the box does not allow to add products with the required custom option to the group or bundle products.

Check this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11633

Comment: Thanks but in my case, i used two extension one of bss- grouped product & another is Pektsekye-OptionExtended so right now having the issue to display those products in admin grid.- working on it @ParthThummar